# Why can't I enable drop shadows on my Windows XP desktop icons?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, desktop-icons

[image: I do not understand this.]

I've been helping my grandfather maintain his old Dell for quite a while now, and every now and then something inexplicable will go wrong. The most recent issue is that the desktop icons refuse to have a drop shadow, regardless of the fact that I have it enabled under System - Advanced - Performance - Settings.

I've tried:

- Disabling and re-enabling it
- Disabling and re-enabling ALL the options under System - Advanced - Performance - Settings
- Switching backgrounds

According to System Restore he hasn't installed any new programs lately, and his computer is virus-free. Everything should be fine.

This one's blowing my mind. I've got nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember for sure...but I believe that happened (once) when I installed google desktop...and from the looks of it you have that installed?

I might try uninstalling google desktop

Comment: That might be a good idea, anyway - I doubt that he uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the desktop and click Properties, then go to the Desktop tab and click *Customise Desktop*. Under the Web tab does it have 'Lock desktop items' ticked?

[image: Desktop web settings]

If so, untick that and the drop shadows should hopefully be restored.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'll look into it when I head over there next.